# Python iterating from the middle of a cycle to before the start

Tags: python, list, iteration, cycle

I've been working on programming a board game to practice python. I use a cycle to do turn order like this:

```
turncycle = [0,1,2,3]
for turnindex in cycle(turncycle):
    #.
    #...turn stuff
    #...turnindex is used for active player
    #.
```

What I want to do is given a turn index start a mini turn where an event-card triggers and they have to something. Is there a way to rebuild the list so I can change [0,1,2,3] into [1,2,3,0] or cycle starting from 1,2, or 3 and then cycle through the rest once?

Comment: turncycle[1:]+[turncycle[0]] perhaps?

Comment: or using *numpy*: `np.roll(turncycle, 1)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. An example of the desired behavior would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
def next_cycle(lst):
    return turncycle[1:] + turncycle[:1]

turncycle = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for turnindex in range(len(turncycle)):
    turncycle = next_cycle(turncycle)
    print turncycle
```

Comment: Imho `turncycle[1:] + turncycle[:1]` looks much nicer and it's easy to generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Cobbled together something from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
import itertools
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(itertools.islice(iterator, n, n), None)

def cycle(turncycle, start = 0):
    # limit to the original number of turns
    no_of_turns = len(turncycle)
    # make a non-ending cycle
    turncycle = itertools.cycle(turncycle)
    # advance to the start position
    consume(turncycle, start)
    # return a new turn cycle - from the itertools take() recipe
    return itertools.islice(turncycle, no_of_turns)

>>> 
>>> for n in cycle(a):
    print(n),

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>>> for n in cycle(a, 4):
    print(n),

4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
>>> for n in cycle(a, 20):
    print(n),

4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
>>>
```

---

`cycle` may need to be tweaked a bit depending on what you think the `start` parameter means.

It could probably be renamed `roll()`.